# Datatables editor

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I'm trying to use datatables editor (https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html) using data from a table of my database and have included all of cdn required, but I can't add data or edit, and when I trace console, it said : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404". Below is my Javascript code using CodeIgniter 4 :

```
<script>
    const editor = new DataTable.Editor({
        ajax: 'tampilkan_ajax',
        fields: [{
                label: 'id:',
                name: 'DT_RowId'
            },
            {
                label: 'Nama:',
                name: 'nama_ta'
            }
            
        ],
        table: '#example'
    });

    new DataTable('#example', {
        ajax: 'tampilkan_ajax',
        buttons: [{
                extend: 'create',
                editor
            },
            {
                extend: 'edit',
                editor
            },
            {
                extend: 'remove',
                editor
            }
        ],
        columns: [{
                data: null,
                render: data => data.id
            },
            {
                data: 'nama_ta'
            }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select: true
    });
```

and this is my code in controller which is called by ajax ('tampilkan_ajax'):

```
        $model = $this->ModelPengalaman = new ModelPengalaman();
        $data = $model->findAll();
        $output = array(
            'data' => $data
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
```

This is picture when I clicked "tampilkan_ajax:1" on console :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D31u1.png
Is there anybody could help me ?

Comment: I close my question,.....I'm sorry for my stupid question.